# Android keyboard input type

Tags: android, android-webview

I am showing android soft keyboard in my webview like this:

```
InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
manager.showSoftInput(myWebview, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Is there a way to specify the input type, for example, to show only numbers?

Note that I'm not using any `EditText` so I can't set that in my view. Wanted to know if it's even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are looking to change keyboard input type depending on the input of the WebView, if so this is the best option.

Set the type of the input field to change the type of keyboard displayed, like so:

http://jsbin.com/eCeJAFaV/4/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p><input type="color" name="color" placeholder="color" /></p>
    <p><input type="date" name="date" placeholder="date" /></p>
    <p><input type="datetime" name="datetime" placeholder="datetime" /></p>
    <p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" /></p>
    <p><input type="month" name="month" placeholder="month" /></p>
    <p><input type="number" name="number" placeholder="number" /></p>
    <p><input type="search" name="search" placeholder="search" /></p>
    <p><input type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="tel" /></p>
    <p><input type="time" name="time" placeholder="time" /></p>
    <p><input type="url" name="url" placeholder="url" /></p>
      <p><input type="week" name="week" placeholder="week" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input type=number>` in your HTML. According to [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs_mobile.html#t04) it's mostly (there are some small bugs) supported from at least Android 2.3. To test whether this is the behaviour you want use [this test page](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/tests/inputs_numbers.html).